# How to configure xterm to delete word after cursor when Ctrl+Del is pressed?

Tags: tcsh, xterm

Currently, I have the below configuration in `.Xresources` file to delete word before cursor on `Ctrl+Backspace`. But, I couldn't figure out the configuration for deleting word after cursor.

```
xterm*VT100*translations:       #override \
    Ctrl <Key> BackSpace: string(0x1b) string(0x8)
```

I am using tcsh.

Comment: What that setting does, is that it translates ctrl-backspace to an "escape, backspace" sequence which tcsh apparently interprets as "delete word backwards". If I remember correctly, "escape ctrl-d" will delete a word to the right. In that case, a similar setting with `string(0x1b) string(0x4)` should do it. But I haven’t used tcsh in 30 years, and xterm not in 15, so I may have some details wrong. =)

Comment: @TurePålsson, No, similar setting with `string(0x1b) string(0x4)` is not working. Still, it deletes only one character.

Comment: Oh, it’s "escape d", not "escape ctrl-d" (at least in the tcsh I have on my Mac), so `string(0x1b) string("d")`, then. It’s probably possible to write that in a single `string`, but I don’t remember the exact syntax.

Comment: Thanks @TurePålsson, `Esc d` works! I added `string(0x1b) string(0x64)` setting for `Ctrl+Delete`. It works as required. You can add it in answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps here: First, Xterm translates a ctrl-backspace key sequence to the (ASCII) characters ESC, BS (1b, 08 in hexadecimal) and then tcsh interprets that as "delete word left". The corresponding tcsh command sequence for "delete word right" is ESC and the letter 'd' (or 'D'), so a similar translation but with `string(0x1b) string(0x64)` (0x64 being the ASCII code for 'D') should do it. (There is probably a shorter way of writing that, but I have not dealt with Xterm keyboard translations in over 15 years and my memory is a bit hazy on the details...)

Comment: It's in the [manpage](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:string): "D" is shorter than "0x64".